# splitting a list into [ ]

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a list of countries. and for each countries I have an area and a population.

i.e  `[Afghanistan, 647500.0, 25500100, Albania,28748.0,2821977]` and like 50 others like this.

I am trying to seperate each group of information into separate [ ] for example:

```
[["Afghanistan",647500.0,25500100],["Albania",28748.0,2821977]]
```

i have this script so far:

```
def readFile():
    # I already have it so it reads the lists of countries.

    try:

        linestring = open(filename).readlines()
        linestring = linestring.split("\r")
        linestring = linestring.split("\n")

            print linestring
```

Comment: are there always 3 elements to group?

Comment: `[Afghanistan, 647500.0, 25500100, Albania,28748.0,2821977]` is not a valid list (assuming that `Afghanistan` and `Albania` aren't variables). What is your _actual_ input and output?

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: the file is a .txt file, and an indent separates the area and population, followed by a line change to the next countries. for example: Afghanistan, 647500.0, 25500100
Albania, 28748.0, 2821977
Algeria, 2381740.0, 38700000

Comment: I think what OP actually needs is to use the [csv module](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/csv.html).

Comment: So many people are posting answers that do what the OP asked for, but not what he needs. It doesn't look like the program actually has the list of mixed countries, areas, and populations in the format shown, so it's possible that none of the grouper answers will be usable.

Comment: exactly. okay i have a .txt file.  and this file contains like 100 countrys with and area and population for each.  this info is layed out like 3 columns.  I need to read the file. and separate all the info with []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New answer**:

Now that I think I understand what the OP is asking, here's a quick demo of using a list comprehension to load a CSV file.

```
>>> arrs = [ l.rstrip().split(",\t") for l in open(filename) ]
```

Then since some of your data are integers, you may want to convert them from strings:

```
>>> data = [ [arr[0], int(arr[1]), int(arr[2])] for arr in arrs ]
```

You may also want to consult the [csv module](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/csv.html), which has functions to do some of this for you.

*Demo for one line*

```
>>> l = "Zimbabwe,\t390580.0,\t12973808\n"
>>> l.rstrip().split(",\t")
['Zimbabwe', '390580.0', '12973808']
```

---

<strike>**Prior Answer**</strike>

A different, easily understandable solution is to split your list into sublists of size 3 with a list comprehension.

```
>>> sublist_size = 3
>>> L = ["Afghanistan", 647500.0, 25500100, "Albania",28748.0,2821977]
>>> grouped = [ L[i:i+sublist_size] for i in range(0, len(L), sublist_size) ]
>>> grouped
[['Afghanistan', 647500.0, 25500100], ['Albania', 28748.0, 2821977]]
```

This solution uses `range` to get the indices where there is a country (every three elements) to split up your original list.

Comment: but i cant use direct text from the list in my script. Python has to read the list--> and then separate each [country,area,population] instantly. when i do i.e readFile("countries.txt") in the shell

Comment: @user3207521: okay I think I understand your issue better now. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: perfect, my countries came up separated with the [ ], but now at the beginning of each group it has \t . how can i get rid of those?

Comment: @user3207521: you can use `strip()` instead of `rstrip()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: i changed it to that and a set is still coming up as        ['Zimbabwe', '\t390580.0', '\t12973808']

Comment: @user3207521: ah I thought you meant that there was one `'\t'` in the beginning. So wherever there is a comma there is also a tab, i.e. `',\t'`? If so, split on both simultaneously: `l.rstrip().split(",\t")`. See the updated code.

Comment: oh wow it worked! wow thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it so much. Is there a direct message box I can reach you at?

Comment: @user3207521: Unfortunately, [StackOverflow doesn't support direct messaging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126569/send-direct-messages), and you need more reputation to chat... My email address is in [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2831353/mdml), though.

Comment: okay well! since I now have the countries separated, how would start if I wanted to search a country i.e: 
getCountry():
canada
and then have it show me the info using a binary search.
Im not sure how to begin this process

Comment: @user3207521: I would use a dictionary. Check out [this tutorial on Python dictionaries](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) and post another question (perhaps with more detail on your input/output than this one :)) if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment describes a tab-delimited, newline-separated text file. Python has a [module](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/csv.html) that facilitates reading and writing from files with exactly that format. An example for your application would be:

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    grouped = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'))
    print grouped
```

There is no need to muck around with splitting and grouping when there is a perfectly good library already for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one easy way to do it:

```
In [5]: l = ['Afghanistan', 647500.0, 25500100, 'Albania',28748.0,2821977]

In [6]: zip(*(l[n::3] for n in range(3)))
Out[6]: [('Afghanistan', 647500.0, 25500100), ('Albania', 28748.0, 2821977)]
```

(It returns tuples rather than lists though. Easy enough to change if it matters to you.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to let python read my file.txt and separate each set of information by [ ]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your current code is flawed.

   ```
   linestring = open(filename).readlines() # returns a list of lines
   linestring = linestring.split("\r") # lists don't have a split method!
   linestring = linestring.split("\n") # even if split worked, this would be a list now
   ```
2. You need to read your file. It's hard to tell what format it's in. You might want to use the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module.
3. It looks like you might want to check out the `grouper` **recipe** from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).